# Replacing null with "" in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I wanted to ask if "" (double-quotes) can be added instead of null in a data frame using pyspark

```
employee_id employee_name  salary
123           abc           null
```

Instead

```
employee_id employee_name  salary
123           abc           ""
```

I tried fillna({'salary': ''}).
O/P  I get is

```
employee_id employee_name  salary
123           abc
```

Could some please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It’s ok what you’re doing. It replaces null values with empty strings. You don’t need those quotes.

However, if you want the double quotes to be part of the data just add them like this :

```
df.na.fill({'salary': '""'})
```

Complete example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(123, "abc", None)], "employee_id int, employee_name string, salary string")

df.show()
#+-----------+-------------+------+
#|employee_id|employee_name|salary|
#+-----------+-------------+------+
#|        123|          abc|  null|
#+-----------+-------------+------+

df = df.na.fill({'salary': '""'})

df.show()
#+-----------+-------------+------+
#|employee_id|employee_name|salary|
#+-----------+-------------+------+
#|        123|          abc|    ""|
#+-----------+-------------+------+
```

Comment: Tried this. But it also gives the same O/P as above

Comment: @Mahima It gives the expected output. Added a working example in the answer. Can you show the example for which it does not work?